# Claims-based or classic authentication mode - how to figure out in a given SharePoint 2010 installation?

Tags: authentication, claims-based-auth, windows-authentication, classic-mode-auth

How do I figure out whether a web application in my SharePoint 2010 farm is using claims-based or classic authentication mode? I know that authentication provider (default zone) is Windows, but according to this article http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262350.aspx, the authentication mode could be either (claims-based or classic) for the Windows authentication method.

The reason I am asiking this is because I believe there is a difference in setup of our staging and production environments in terms of authentication mode, which is causing issues with user profile extraction.

Thank you in advance for any help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check this [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/sreejukg/archive/2011/03/25/change-sharepoint-authentication-from-classic-mode-to-claims-based.aspx) to see if it provides clues.

Comment: Nitin, thanks for the answer. Based on this article, I guess in Central Admin, if the Authentication Provider is marked as Windows, it is classic authentication. If it is marked as Claims-Based, then it is claims based authentication.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  the property [`SPWebApplication.UseClaimsAuthentication`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebapplication.useclaimsauthentication.aspx) to determine whether claims based authentication is enabled or not.

Comment: Stefan, thank you for your answer; I was looking to get a clue from Central Admin before having to check it through the code.

Answer (score 0):

Classic authentication Mode: when u have selected classic authentication mode that time web application take Window authentication credentials.

claims-based authentication Mode: In Claims-based authentication configure with FBA database.you are just specify the Provider and Membership Users using IIS Configuration.you want to add multiple Users access yours web application with them own Credentials. than its better ways to go claims-based authentication.  Here good link for configured Claims-based.

[Here good link for configured Claims-based](http://donalconlon.wordpress.com/2010/02/23/configuring-forms-base-authentication-for-sharepoint-2010-using-iis7/)

Answer (score 0):

I've always found a quick glance into the Authentication settings in IIS gives a clue to whether basic authentication is being used or not...

[image]